# Updating state on route change with React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am using React + Redux and want to know how to update state correctly.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>

      <Route path="/questions" component={App}>
        <Route path="subject">
          <Route path="english" component={displayQuestions} />
          <Route path="math"    component={displayQuestions} />
          <Route path="science" component={displayQuestions} />
          <Route path="history" component={displayQuestions} />
        </Route>
      </Route>

      ...

    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.app'));
```

These routes can be clicked on with tabs (one example shown here):

```
<div>
    <Link to={'/questions/english'}>English</Link>
</div>

...
```

In my render method for displayQuestions, I do a check

```
if (!questions) {
    Loading content
}

return (
    {this.renderQuestions()}
)
```

So when a user navigates to the page, in my componentDidMount(), I use an action method, this.props.fetchQuestions, and then it makes the async request to my backend, goes through the reducers and then into the render method above. In the renderQuestions function, And in renderQuestions, I just grab the questions from this.props.questions.

But, the way I have the routes configured, componentDidMount only occurs one time. For example, if I select on the english tab, I get the componentDidMount, but if I then click on math or science, the url changes, but componentDidMount isn't called again.

If I hit a button, that uses a different component, like userProfile, then everything rerenders as expected. But I think since I am using the same component in each of the questions/subjects paths, componentDidMount isn't getting called again.

So how can I update the state on url changes? What is React + Redux way? No anti-patterns please.

EDIT:

For now, I have come to this answer:

```
      componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {

        if (this.props.route.path !== nextProps.route.path) {
          let subject = this.props.location.pathname.split('/')[3];
          this.props.fetchQuestions(subject);
        }

        return false;
      }
```

This stops the infinite loop that would otherwise occur. But there must be a better way.

Comment: I am not sure about it, but I think you should do it on componentWillReceiveProps

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact layout of your components but it sounds like your "Tabs" component are all one component that gets mounted once. If that is the case, then there is probably some state that controls which tab to show right? You can then do a check in `componentWillReceiveProps` for when your props have changed to the questions tab. If it has then do your async request.

For example

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.tab === 'questionTab' && this.props.tab !== 'questionTab' ) {
    this.props.fetchQuestions();
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, using componentWillUpdate causes an infinite loop. On update, the async request is made, when new movies are returned, componentWillUPdate is invoked, and it continues ad infinitum.

Comment: Ah I meant to add a check that if the current props isn't already the question tab. That way the `fetchQuestions` is only called when the tab changes to the questions tab.

Comment: I edited the answer, as suggested by jro, I believe this should use `componentWillReceiveProps` and not  `componentWillUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

The Link [to property](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#to) can receive an [LocationDescriptor](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#locationdescriptor) object instead of just pathname. Using the location descriptor you can pass a state that you can check in the component [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) method. However, componentWillReceiveProps is not called when the component mounts, so you will also have to make this call when the component mounts - [componentWillMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount). Better make one method for fetching, and invoke it from both of them:

```
<div>
    <Link to={ 
               pathname: '/questions/subject', 
               state: { subject: 'english'} 
    }>English</Link>

    <Link to={ 
               pathname: '/questions/subject', 
               state: { subject: 'science'} 
    }>English</Link>
</div>

/** now you can declare only one route, and the state invokes the change **/
<Route path="/questions" component={App}>
    <Route path="subject" component={displayQuestions} />
</Route>

class displayQuestions extends React.Component {
    _updateQuestions(props, nextProps) {
          const currentSubject = props.location.state.subject; // the current subject
          const nextSubject = nextProps ? nextProps.location.state.subject : null; // the nextSubject (componentWillReceiveProps) or null (componentWillMount)
          if(currentSubject  === nextProps) { // if the subjects are equal do nothing
              return;
          }

          props.fetchQuestions(nextSubject || currentSubject); // fetch the questions of nextSubject (componentWillReceiveProps) or currentSubject (componentWillMount)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
          _updateQuestions(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
          _updateQuestions(this.props, nextProps);
    }
}
```